# Context switching issue in appium mobile automation

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

Hi I tried switching from native to hybrid pages in mobile automation . it throws an error  chrome driver  is already in use. How to fix it in mobile automation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automate android app using java, you can switch between contexts using the below method.

```
public final String WEBVIEW = "WEBVIEW_com.maxsoft.testextractor";
public final String NATIVE_APP = "NATIVE_APP";

public void switchContextTo(String context){
        if (context.toLowerCase().equals(WEBVIEW.toLowerCase())) {
            androidDriver.context(WEBVIEW); // set context to WEBVIEW_1
        } else {
            androidDriver.context(NATIVE_APP); // set context to NATIVE_APP
        }
    }
```